# Why is there an yellow exclamation dot when I added a project reference in Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I added a class library project into a Silverlight Business Application project. The class library project contains the entities that will be used in the solutiion.  I added a reference to the library in both the client and the web projects of the solution, however, although it seems to work, in the web project it shows the reference with an yellow exclamation dot. (!) 
Does anyone knows what is this and what it means?

Comment: I found out that the yellow exclamation dot means that the library is missing but how come I'm still able to access its methods from the web project? What is wrong and what are the implications on keep working in the project with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio might have not refreshed the (!)symbol correctly. Try to rebuild your solution and reopen VS.

Also, make sure to add the reference via the "Projects" Tab and not "Browse" to the dll in the output folder.

Comment: I did all that but the exclamation dot still remain, although it is only in the web project.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are Targeting the same .NET Framework version in all of your projects. Click properties on your project. Select 'Application' on the side tab. Verify the target framework matches in all of your projects.